# Ранжирование товара из sqlite бд по рейтингу

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, база-данных, sqlite

Есть база данных sqlite с товаром, у ним есть поле rating, я хочу при помощи nodejs и пакета sqlite3 доставать из бд карточки товара и отправлять их, но я их сортирую по полю рейтинг чтобы отдавались самые лучшие товары. Проблемы заключается в том что мне отдаёт только пятизвёздочные товары и не даёт шанса показать другие оценки допустим 4,8 как сделать чтобы при сортировке иногда попадались товары низкого рейтинга (5, 5,4.2,4.9,5)

Comment: Тут только придумывать, как организовать дополнительную выборку таваров.  Может взять случайные товары по имени или еще по кокомуто полю. Универсального решения не существует...

Comment: `select * from product where rating >= 4 order by random()`

Comment: Используйте рандомайзер для выбора и напишите условие, что допустим через каждые две оценки будет попадаться 100% пятерка

Comment: Ну например ```ORDER BY rating + RAND() * N```. Чем больше N (значение - единица плюс/минус), тем более вероятно появление в списке низкорейтинговых товаров.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь всем, ваши советы мне помогли

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задача решается при помощи строки:
`ORDER BY rating + random() * N`
Но паралельно с этим я вычетал про функции: ROW_NUMBER, NTILE, RANK и DENSE_RANK в sql.
Думаю что в дальнейшем попробую использовать их, всем спасибо!